Set property without mapping in mapper Java Mapstruct
I have a mapper like:
Cat toAnotherCat(Cat origin);
And I need an another mapper like that (CatsHouse has a property: Cat oneOfCats;):
CatsHouse toNewCatsHouse(CatsHouse catsHouse)
When I run Maven build, in toNewCatsHouse implementation I see newCatHouse.setOneOfCats(toAnotherCat(catsHouse.getOneOfCats()))
But I need newCatHouse.setOneOfCats(catsHouse.getOneOfCats()) instead of this
How can I get it? How can I prohibit to use toAnotherCat automatically?

I found the solution: using MappingControl.Use.DIRECT
I create an annotation:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@MappingControl( MappingControl.Use.DIRECT )
public @interface DirectMappingControl {
}

And use on toNewCatsHouse:
@Mapping(target = "oneOfCats", mappingControl = DirectMappingControl.class)
